# When Have All The Views In A Fragment Been Given A Size?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Without resorting to the infamous `onGlobalLayoutListener()` solution, and without having to implement a custom View, what lifecycle event in a Fragment can I put code into and be sure all of the Fragment's Views have been given a size?

As a corollary, I would also like this lifecycle event to be applicable to Fragments in a ViewPager.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think there would be any Fragment lifecycle event to be sure all the Views have size.

What I would usually do is, to use OnLayoutChangeListener inside onActivityCreated(). Like this,

```
getView().addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                getView().removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);

                // Check the size of Views here.
            }
        });
```

Comment: Is it the case that the Fragments Views have not had their Size set when `onActivityCreated()` is called, and they have when this callback is made? Does it make a difference where we attach this listener? For example, could we attach it in `onCreateView()` or `onViewCreated()`?

Comment: Yes, there is no guarantee that the Fragment Views have their size set when `onActivityCreated()` is called (I have checked that). OnLayoutChangeListener gets callback when the bounds of the View changes. So it will get callback when the Views have their size set. I have seen some Googler's code using this listener for this purpose.

Comment: To answer your second question, I usually do nothing but inflate the Fragment layout inside `onCreateView()`, and do all initializations inside `onActivityCreated()`, because `onActivityCreated()` gets called only after the parent Activity's `onCreate()` has been completed. So, I will get the View references inside `onActivityCreated()` only and I will set the `OnLayoutChangeListener` after that. So that I can be sure that the Views used inside the listener will not be null.